# Unable to download update to Lollipop

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, ota-update, android-versions, samsung-galaxy-grand-2

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Grand 2. I'm unable to download the upgrade to Lollipop. While downloading via Wifi it says "Unable to Download...."

Comment: my wifi is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also update with Samsung Kies on your computer.

Comment: Ya I tried it .. but the thing is it hangs up(kies).. I think something is wrong with the Samsung Galaxy 2 Lollipop update.. what do u think?

Comment: Could you send a screenshot when updating?